# Dynamic pivot table in bi publisher template

Tags: pivot-table, bi-publisher

I want to generate different pivot table in a template.I have some orders that contain several items and qty.I want to create an output that shows every orders in separate table.

[image]

The desire output is:

[image]

and the data set is:

![enter image description here][3]

thanks

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: update your question with the images embedded, people don't want to click on links.  Pretend you are asking a very busy colleague for help. :)